# Making bootable USB flash drive with dd

Tags: arch-linux, bootable-media, dd

I'm trying to make my 32GB flash drive bootable with archlinux. Beginning from release 2010.05, all ISO files can be directly written to USB media.
So, what I've did:

```
dd if=archlinux.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Copying has succesfully finished, but I still can't boot from my flash drive.

Are there any additional things, that I should to do? Or, maybe, some flash drive is not able to be bootable? Or what I've missed?

Comment: Pro tip: use cp instead of dd. No fiddling with blocksizes, works well and is less complicated to use, thus involving less errors. Remeber to sync afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, problem was on computer side. And it start to works, when I manually chose my flash drive to boot.

But I don't know why the boot device priority with flash drive on the top hadn't made the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

I think you will have to create a FAT32 partition (so, say, `/dev/sdc1`) that is the same size as the ISO, then use `dd` to copy to it. Then use `parted` or some other tool to mark the partition as bootable. If it is the same device, then you would type `parted /dev/sdc` then type `set 1 boot on`.

I'm not certain about this, so make sure you use the right device and that you've backed up everything important off it if you haven't already.

EDIT: [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) might be able to make the process easier. It specifically says it supports ArchLinux 2010.05.

Comment: This won't make a difference, dd will overwrite the partition table anyway.

Comment: @Rob Not if you specify a partition rather than the device, i.e. "create a FAT32 partition... then use `dd` to copy to it [the partition `/dev/sdc1`]."

Comment: I'm bad at reading, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I want to post my experience.

It took me a while to understand how to create a live-usb with arch linux. The solution is simple. I just wrote:

$ dd if=/adress/of/iso-file of=/adress/of/usb-stick/sda/not/sdaY/don't/write/the/partition/number

I worked a lot with gnome disk utility and gparted. It's okay to clear the partition table of the USB-Stick.

One interesting fact is important. If dd ends with just 100-400 files, then something went wrong. Sometimes it took more time but I abborted because I didn't want to wait so long. Then I did once until it's finished. I'm sure it took about 20 minutes that time and suddely dd shows up with about 10000 files correctly transmitted. I booted the stick and everything works fine. I didn't know about the amount of files and I think if you do it the way I did (as you can see I didn't use the bs=part) and wait about 30 minutes, everything should be fine.

An USB 3.0 stick really can help you.

Comment: (1) How is what you did different from what the OP did?  (2) What are you talking about with `dd` transmitting files?

Comment: (3) Note that this answer is identical (down to the same typos) to [this one on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/211240/80216) (by the same new user).